# Email Table Images being centered

Tags: html, css

My images are centering in a table cell. I have tried using `text-align: left`, however when you send it in an email the images are still centered.

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l {
    vertical-align: top;
}
img {max-width:100%;}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}}
```

```html
<div class="tg-wrap">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">
                <a href="http://www.highprofile-properties.co.uk/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ap6gok8.png"></a>

            </th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5YgxaJ3.png" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom:25px;"><br>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hYv3F1R.png" style="margin-bottom:5px;"><br>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hYv3F1R.png" style="margin-bottom:5px;"><br>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/acXC4op.png" style="margin-bottom:5px;"><br>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uQVx0nh.png">
            </th>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
    <div style="max-width:600px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#838383;">
    <p>The information in this message is confidential and may be legally privileged. It is intended solely for the addressee. Access to this message by any other person is not permitted. If you are not the intended recipient, any disclosure, copying, distribution or any action taken or omitted to be taken in reliance on it, is prohibited and may be unlawful.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any one knows how to make them left aligned?

Comment: Different e-mail clients support different versions of HTML and/or CSS. Also keep in mind that many e-mail clients only support a subset of the HTML/CSS standards, so without telling us in which e-mail client (name, version, platform) your table doesn't look correctly, it's impossible to give a useful reply to this question.

Comment: apply inline styles to your table and th like `<table class="tg" style="text-align:left">`

Comment: In the current version the images on the right table are still center-aligned because you didn't apply `text-align:left` as @SureshPonnukalai said. I would make sure that the images have `display:inline-block` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
img {max-width:100%; float: left;}
```

or

```
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0; text-align: left;}
```